# Datatable - pagination - get records in a particular page

Tags: angular, primeng

Is there any way to get the records in a particular page in PrimeNG datatable with Angular 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You have #pages and #recordsPerPage available.  You could calculate the beginning index of a record for the page you want, then take the next #recoredsPerPage number ...

So page 3 with 20 records per page would be a starting index of the data array at 59 and go to 78.  So you would splice the array beginning at index 59 and take the next 20 records...